# Editing My Site in SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, error, my-site

When I try to edit My Site in SharePoint Designer I get the following:

[image]

So I have gone into Central Admin. Gone to my web application and have checked the SharePoint Designer section

[image: enter code here]

All looks good.

Under Authentication I have Client Integration checked.

[image]

In Site Collection Administration for the site I have the following for SharePoint Designer Settings.

[image]

I have also performed an `iisreset` on the central admin server.

The user account I am using is a Site Collection Administrator.

What else could be wrong?

Comment: Are any custom solutions deployed that would override the SharePoint Designer settings?

Comment: The only custom feature deployed staples on the publishing feature to all sites. The my sites was created before this feature was added.